# Write filename using sstream and fstream in C++

Tags: c++

In my c++ program, I am saving output data in a file using sprintf and fstream just like below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

char outname[50];
int n = 100;
sprintf(outname, "output_%s_%d.dat", "file", n);

ofstream fout;    
fout.open(outname);
```

How could I get a filename using std::sstring instead of sprintf and open that file with std::ofstream ? In above code filename is outname, which is being opened with std::ofstream.

Comment: Can you clarify this? Do you want the name *generated* with a `std::ostringstream`, or the name *written to the file* (as in the name is used to *open* the file *and* is written *into* the file as the first data)? I ask because the code you have *now* doesn't "write the outname into fout" regardless of the mechanics used to generate it.

Comment: Yes, I want to generate the filename using std::ostringstream instead of sprintf, and open that file using std::ofstream.

Comment: but not write the filename *into* the file *content*, right? It was the choice of vernacular ("...write the 'outname' into 'fout'...") that confused me.

Comment: Yes I do not want to write filename into the content. In my code output file is outname which is being opened with std::ofstream. I am getting the filename "outname" from sprintf on 5th line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe something like this?

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream outname;

outname << "output_file_" << n << ".dat";
...
ofstream fout;
fout.open( outname.str().c_str() );
```

Comment: it is called c_str() note the underscore but it think ofstream can take a std::string directly, see above.

Comment: Thanks, it works now with c_str(). Without using c_str() it yields error to me. I had tried the same before posting question.